# Connect SQL Express Database to Team Foundation Express

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, tfs

I finally managed to use Team Foundation Express with Visual Studio Express for Web 2012 but I want to connect the database (SQL Server Express 2012) that I've created. Is there any way to do that in SQL Server Management Studio?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, although the built in source control in SQL Management Studio is a bit clunky, a better option is RedGate's SQL Source Control:

[RedGate SQL Source Control](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-source-control/)

This works brilliantly for us and is really simple to use.

If you want to use the native source control in the management studio you have to install some bits and pieces:

1/ You need Team Explorer 2012 installed (I think you need to have Visual Studio 2012 installed, but you can always install the express version of that too in order to get it working if you don't have an install of that already):

[Team Explorer 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=30656)

2/ Then you need to install the TFS MSSCCI Provider (chose either 32 or 64 bit depending on your Visual Studio installation):

[Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2012 MSSCCI Provider 32-bit](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b5b5053e-af34-4fa3-9098-aaa3f3f007cd)

[Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2012 MSSCCI Provider 64-bit](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3c7b6813-2617-4d5f-9a1d-5ad980cab5d2)

3/ Then you need to set up SQL Management Studio to use source control:

- Click Tools -> Options -> Source Control -> Plugin Selection -> Select the MSSCCI provider you just installed
- Right Click on the menu bar and select to show the source control toolbar (hidden by default)
- Open a .sql file and then click the "Change Source Control" button, you can then use this dialog to enter your server details and add your files to your team project etc

Just to add, with the built in source control, I don't think you can add a database itself to source control, just SQL scripts, with RedGate, you can add the whole database and combine source control and SQL compare to create migration scripts between versions, the built in source control is very basic.